# how to grab two IDs? 1: post_id and another parent_id of comments on cakePHP 2.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, comments, cakephp-2.0

I do have a view for posts and comments are related to posts. Comments generateTreeList and are part of post view. I also have bootstrap modal as element 'reply.ctp' which is again part of the post view. Form is posting the comment with post_id and is not grabboing the 'parent_id'. Any clues that leads will be quite more than helpful. In other words, what I am trying to do is: grab, post_id of Post, parent_id of comments and trying to save comments as a reply. And I am clueless.

@Fazel Rasel

Following is the add action from commentsController.php:

```
public function add($post_id = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Comment->set(array('post_id'=>$post_id));
        if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your comment has been added.');
            //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
           //$this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $parentComments = $this->Comment->ParentComment->find('list')
        $posts = $this->Comment->Post->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('parentComments', 'posts'));
       }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show us your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Work with Elements!

Setup an element in "app/View/Elements/Comments/reply-post.ctp" like:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Comment');
echo $this->Form->input('parent_id', array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('post_id', array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('comment');
echo $this->Form->submit('Submit my Comment');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Now, just call that element in your view:

```
<?php
echo $this->element('Comments/reply-post', array('Comment'=>array('post_id'=>$post_id, 'parent_id'=>$parent_id)));
?>
```

You can call this for each comment inside a hidden div, or you can manage a unique form inside a modal using an jQuery function, for example:

```
function CommentPost(_post_id, _comment_id){
    if (_comment_id==undefined) _comment_id = '';
    $('#CommentPostId').val(_post_id);
    $('#CommentParentId').val(_comment_id);
    $('#myModal').modal();
}
```

Link to post a single comment:

```
<a href="javascript:void(CommentPost('<?php echo $post_id; ?>'));">Post a Comment</a>
```

To post a reply to an comment:

```
<a href="javascript:void(CommentPost('<?php echo $post_id; ?>', '<?php echo $comment_id; ?>'));">Post a Reply</a>
```

Comment: @ Newton Pasqualini Filho: Getting Notice 8: Undefined variable: post_id [APP\View\Posts\view.ctp, line 54]', ' Notice (8): Undefined variable: comment_id [APP\View\Posts\view.ctp, line 54] And online I have: 

    "<a href="javascript:void(CommentPost('<?php echo $post_id; ?>', '<?php echo $comment_id; ?>'));">Post a Reply</a>". And as you suggested, div I do have jquery function in a hidden div in Post view.ctp. Not even href link is showing. – –